# How can I pass UITextField string from SecondViewController to array in Model Class?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a flash card app with a model and two view controllers. In the first scene I display the questions and answers, cycling through the arrays of questions and answers. The questions and answers arrays are stored in the Model class. The second scene/view controller's purpose is t be able to edit the questions and answers by editing the text in the `UITextField`s and after pressing the OK button, the questions and answers arrays are updated to the text in the TextFields.

When editing the "question" and "answer" text fields in the Second ViewController, changes to those strings have to be applied to the same FlashCardModel object that is used in the First Scene.

How do I update the questions array in the model class with the value of the questionTextField?

```
//  FlashCardModel.swift
//  TabbedFlashCards
//
//
//
//

import Foundation

class FlashCardModel {
    var currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    var questions = ["What is 1*7?", "What is 2*7?", "What is 3*7?"]
    var answers = ["7", "14", "21"]

    init(){
        //Any useful Constructor code would go here
    }

    func getNextQuestion() -> String{
        currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex + 1;
        if(currentQuestionIndex >= questions.count){
            currentQuestionIndex = 0;
        }
        return questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }

    func getAnswer() -> String{
        return answers[currentQuestionIndex]
    }

    func getCurrentQuestion() -> String{
        return questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }

    func setCurrentQuestion(pString : String){
        questions[currentQuestionIndex] = pString
    }

    func setCurrentAnswer(pString : String){
        answers[currentQuestionIndex] = pString
    }
}//End of model

//
//  SecondViewController.swift
//  TabbedFlashCards
//
//

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    // the reference to our AppDelegate:
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate?
    // the reference to our data model:
    var myFlashCardModel: FlashCardModel?

    @IBOutlet weak var questionTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func buttonOKAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        self.myFlashCardModel = self.appDelegate?.myFlashCardModel

        var text: String = questionTextField.text!

        //myFlashCardModel?.setCurrentQuestion(pString: editQuestion)
        //print ("self.questionTextField.text = \(self.questionTextField.text)")
        //print ("self.answerTextField.text = \(self.answerTextField.text)")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.questionTextField.text = "Question"
        self.answerTextField.text = "Answer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `self.myFlashCardModel.setCurrentQuestion(pString: text)` in your `buttonOKAction(sender:)` method?

Comment: Also, you will probably find it easier if you store an array of a struct that contains both the question and the answer rather than trying to co-ordinate two arrays

Comment: One other point, although you are doing the right thing by conditionally casting to `AppDelegate`, this is probably one of the places where you can use an implicitly unwrapped optional and a force cast - If your application delegate class *isn't* AppDelegate then something has gone seriously wrong and you will find it quite quickly during development.  It isn't the sort of thing that can suddenly fail after release.  Assigning to `self.appDelegate` and `self.myFlashCardModel` would probably be better in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Your model `class FlashCardModel` is well defined. It has information about the current state and has appropriate functions to modify both the question and the answer. And it seems like, your model is instantiated in your `AppDelegate`. (Though not a recommended thing but it should work!). I am assuming you have defined a `var myFlashCardModel = FlashCardModel()` (It is a `var` not `let` as you want to modify it.) and in the `class AppDelegate`.

I suspect problem to be, that first view controller has its own model instance instead of accessing the one defined in AppDelegate.